# iphone autorotation animation

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, rotation, autorotate

Is it possible to turn off the animation for the autorotation? I want it to rotate, but I just dont want the animation to occur (like an instant switch).

Comment: Animation is the beauty of it!

Comment: Well i have it set up so that the BG image changes to either a horiz, or vert version of the image depending on the orientation and the rotation animation was causing a glitch when the image changed but I played with it and got it to look okay anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the following code to overwrite the standard rotation animation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:)   name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {
    orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationUnknown || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp){
        orientation = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait;
    }
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:orientation animated:NO];
    [self positionScreenElements];
}
```

Comment: This answer worked great, but I had some issues when focusing a textfield. If the iPad was laying flat on the desk, then the keyboard was showing up half offscreen - very odd.  
  
The issue was that the device orientation could also be unknown, face up, or face down, none of which correspond to a status bar orientation. Checking for those states made this perfect.  
  
Many thanks Nils for saving me w/ this solution :)

Comment: What is "orientation" ?

Answer (score 7):

If you really need to, just use `setAnimationsEnabled` of `UIView`:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]; // disable animations temporarily
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES]; // rotation finished, re-enable them
}
```

It does the trick for me. Of course it's not recommended to do this unless you have a very good reason to do it.

Answer (score 0):

@Nils Munch unfortunately this does not work properly, the setStatusBarOrientation expects `UIInterfaceOrientation` not `UIDeviceOrientation` and casting is bad practice. Correct me if I am wrong